# Kafka Streams restore-consumer not updating IPs (DNS)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams app connecting to bootstrap url via `host.com:port`.

If my Kafka Broker IPs change and I then trigger a Kafka Streams rebalance by adding a new KStream instance I can see the KStreams restore-consumer gets stuck trying to connect to old Broker IPs.

I am not getting any errors logged:

```
INFO | kstream-sample-67928ec5-cdc1-416e-a680-a6686c020023-StreamThread-1                                   | org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient
            | [Consumer clientId=kstream-sample-67928ec5-cdc1-416e-a680-a6686c020023-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Disconnecting from node 1 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 25409 ms.
```

But I can see it's stuck in a loop trying to connect to old Broker IPs

```
WARN | kstream-sample-67928ec5-cdc1-416e-a680-a6686c020023-StreamThread-1                                   | org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                       | [Consumer clientId=kstream-sample-67928ec5-cdc1-416e-a680-a6686c020023-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Connection to node 5 (20.56.29.123/20.56.29.123:25624) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I've tried both `use_all_dns_ips` & `resolve_canonical_bootstrap_servers_only`. But neither works. I've also tried reduce `metadata.max.age.ms`

```java
props.put(StreamsConfig.restoreConsumerPrefix(CommonClientConfigs.CLIENT_DNS_LOOKUP_CONFIG), ClientDnsLookup.RESOLVE_CANONICAL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_ONLY.toString());
props.put(StreamsConfig.restoreConsumerPrefix(CommonClientConfigs.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG), 500);
```

I'm on `<kafka.version>3.2.3</kafka.version>`

Any advice on how to debug further?
Any pointers as to where in the kafka-client code the DNS lookup should re-trigger for the restore-consumer?

UPDATE:

- I've also tried set JVM TTL
  `java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "1");`
- I'm using Aiven Kafka and as part of the upgrade the Broker get completely new VMs and IPs. The bootstrap url is of the form `public-my-kafka.aivencloud.com:25624`

Comment: Try adding `-Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=1` as a JVM argument to your app

Comment: yip should have mentioned I already have `java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "5");`

Comment: Hmm. Why are broker IPs changing at all? Does the broker storage also move to that new server?

Comment: I'm using Aiven Kafka and as part of the upgrade the Broker get completely new VMs and IPs.
The bootstrap url is of the form `public-my-kafka.aivencloud.com:25624`

Comment: I feel like this is a problem that should be discussed with Aiven Support, then. What do they suggest?

Answer (score 0):

It could also be related to DNS caching inside the JVM though, as already mentioned on the comments.

If DNS caching is not the issue, you might hit https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13467